# How to shift focus in jquery?

Tags: jquery, focus, mozilla

I have a field and then a button in my form. I have some focus problem in mozilla. So, I decided to do it using focus evnet of jquery. `$('.button-id').focus();` is not working for me. So, can i do this in jquery:
As some one writing in the input field and when hit enter keyword the focus shifts from input field to button.

Comment: if you bring some of your html you would get a batter answer ! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you give your input field `type="submit"`, browsers should do this automatically.

Then, if you want your button to do something other than submit the form, you can handle the submit event:

```
$("#form-id").submit(function() {
    //do something
    return false; //don't submit
});
```

Comment: type="submit" is not working in mozilla. I need to hit twice the 'return' key